# Track progress of pyspark job?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

We use pyspark in our project. I want to provide a progress update to the user while a Spark job is running. There is Spark UI but I cannot find anything where I can use it in the code, and send the status back to the frontend.

Answer (score 2):

YARN or Kubernetes as Reource Manager?

**For YARN**

How about this? https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/monitoring.html#rest-api
Use the supplied RESTAPI.

> In addition to viewing the metrics in the UI, they are also available
> as JSON. This gives developers an easy way to create new
> visualizations and monitoring tools for Spark. The JSON is available
> for both running applications, and in the history server. The
> endpoints are mounted at /api/v1. For example, for the history server,
> they would typically be accessible at
> http://:18080/api/v1, and for a running application, at
> http://localhost:4040/api/v1.
>
> In the API, an application is referenced by its application ID,
> [app-id]. When running on YARN, each application may have multiple
> attempts, but there are attempt IDs only for applications in cluster
> mode, not applications in client mode. Applications in YARN cluster
> mode can be identified by their [attempt-id]. In the API listed below,
> when running in YARN cluster mode, [app-id] will actually be
> [base-app-id]/[attempt-id], where [base-app-id] is the YARN
> application ID.
> ...

**For Spark on Kubernetes**

How about this? https://www.acceldata.io/blog/how-to-monitor-spark-on-kubernetes
Use the supplied RESTAPI with Kubernetes considerations. It is a blurb about their product, but the key point i as per below.

> ... To access the Spark UI on Kubernetes, you need to port forward to
> it by running
>
> $ kubectl port-forward 4040:4040
>
> It can then be opened at http://localhost:4040/. ...

That said, Spark on Kubernetes has its own set of issues. See https://www.lightbend.com/blog/how-to-manage-monitor-spark-on-kubernetes-introduction-spark-submit-kubernetes-operator for Kubernetes Operator for Spark. All the go K8, but wih all sorts of issues. I'm sticking to Notebook approach and getting on with delivering something, when I do such work. In conjunction wth serverless.

Answer (score 0):

For running a spark on distributed system, you need to make sure where you want to run it, various cloud services provides a nice and easy solution to setup spark architecture which includes monitoring through YARN. You can setup spark architecture on your own but it is becomes difficult to manage like manage memory, setup monitoring . Let me explain in better way (look below diagram)

[image]

For running a spark you can use two ways

1. Single node architecture ->  (generally recommended for running spark locally ), driver node acts as master and worker, chances of data spilling is more thats why it is not recommended for larger datasets
2. Multi node architecture -> This is generally suggested with bigger datasets, understand diagram in the below link as this is not what you have asked.

[https://intellipaat.com/blog/tutorial/spark-tutorial/spark-architecture/#:~:text=The%20Apache%20Spark%20framework%20uses,real%2Dtime%20processing%20as%20well](https://intellipaat.com/blog/tutorial/spark-tutorial/spark-architecture/#:%7E:text=The%20Apache%20Spark%20framework%20uses,real%2Dtime%20processing%20as%20well).

It has multiple worker nodes which is managed by resource manager/cluster manager such as Yarn, Mesos and so on. Now look at diagram, if you create a this diagram our own server you need to manage it which can be tedious. here is some cloud services which takes care of it  and let you provide this services cheaper.

1. AWS EMR
2. Microsoft HDInsight
3. Google Datarpoc
4. Snowflake snowpark

I recommend using these services which lets you see each application on YARN and also allows use set of the different worker machines/cluster according to your need.

Obviously this is not best answer because your question needs to be very concise but do let me know if you found anything useful.